# Select NOT IN from a predefined list

Tags: mysql, sql

For simplicity, suppose I have a table `transactions` with `id` as the primary key.  Currently there are only 10 rows in the table with id from 1 to 10.

I have a list of ids: {9,10,**11**,**12**}.  This list is not stored in the database.

I want to query the database for the ids not in the `transactions` table.  In the case above I want to get 11, 12.

What's the best way to way to write this query?

Currently I just query `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id IN (9,10,11,12)`.  And do my intersection in code.  I'm wondering is I can do it all in one step in SQL.

Comment: Create a table with the id values you want to match. Use that table as the outer table of a left join. Gordon's answer is the same as mine.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id NOT IN (9,10,11,12)`?

Comment: Because the data you want to select isn't data available in the table. You'll never get an 11 or 12 since it's not present.

Comment: Is there any reference or limit for the IDs that aren't on that table? I'm asking because "the IDs that aren't" is a sentence to tend to infinite. Any natural number > 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery containing the ids.  Here is one way:

```
select ids.id
from (select 9 as id union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
     ) ids
where not exists (select 1 from transactions t where t.id = ids.id);
```

Returning rows from a table called `transactions` seems inefficient -- way too much data going back and forth for what you need.  (Although you only have 10 rows, so this isn't a big deal with your data size.)

Comment: These queries are showing up in my Slow Query Log.  Maybe I should use memory table.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use the [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) clause. For example;

```
select 9 as id union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
except select id from transactions
```